# Kafka - In PartitionOffsetRequestInfo what does the maxNumOffsets mean?

Tags: java, apache-kafka

New to Kafka.

- In `PartitionOffsetRequestInfo` what does the `maxNumOffsets` do?
- I also can't figure out what the offsetRequestVersion is for?

I don't seem to be able to find a javadoc that actually explains what these parameters mean.

I do know I can create a `OffsetRequest` (I just like to understand it a bit better):

```
final Map<TopicAndPartition, PartitionOffsetRequestInfo> requestInfo = new HashMap<TopicAndPartition, PartitionOffsetRequestInfo>();
final short version = kafka.api.OffsetRequest.CurrentVersion();
requestInfo.put(topicAndPartition, new PartitionOffsetRequestInfo(time, 1));
final OffsetRequest request = new OffsetRequest(requestInfo, version, name);
```